# What are some proper ways to say in the following situation?

Tags: expressions

I was wondering if there are any considerate and polite ways to express something like "I shouldn't have shared my negative emotion with you" after talking about some bad experience with your friend that you don't think he/she cares even though you want to have a listener.

Or is it even a thing in American culture?

Comment: I think the way you expressed it is already considerate and polite. A more informal way of saying it might be something like "I'm sorry I dumped all that on you; I really needed to talk about it."

Comment: Thank you for letting me get that out.